# Idempotent Amqp.inboundAdapter()

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

How could I implement an idempotent Amqp.inboundAdapter()?

I've tried to use the IdempotentReceiverInterceptor but it doesn't work with MessageProducers.

**EDIT**

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow someFlow(/*...*/) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "myqueue")
        .transform(Transformers.fromJson(), c -> c.advice(idempotentInterceptor))
        .channel("anotherChannel.input")
        .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply apply the interceptor to the first component downstream of the inbound adapter. If the first channel is pub/sub then add a bridge.

Alternatively, you can write a custom advice and add it to the inbound adapter's container's advice chain.

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So40289644Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So40289644Application.class, args);
        RabbitTemplate template = context.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);
        template.convertAndSend("myqueue", "foo");
        template.convertAndSend("myqueue", "bar");
        context.getBean(CountDownLatch.class).await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        context.getBean(RabbitAdmin.class).declareQueue(new Queue("myqueue"));
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public CountDownLatch latch() {
        return new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow someFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "myqueue"))
                .channel("in")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "in", adviceChain = "idempotentInterceptor", outputChannel = "next")
    public JsonToObjectTransformer transformer() {
        return Transformers.fromJson();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow remaining() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("next")
            .handle(m -> {
                System.out.println(m);
                latch().countDown();
            })
            .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IdempotentReceiverInterceptor idempotentInterceptor() {
        IdempotentReceiverInterceptor interceptor = new IdempotentReceiverInterceptor(
                m -> !(new String(((byte[]) m.getPayload())).equals("\"foo\"")));
        interceptor.setDiscardChannel(new NullChannel());
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("myqueue");
    }
```

Comment: I edited my question. I put my interceptor in a transformer advice but it didn't work. Could you show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There's a bug in the DSL - it doesn't apply the advice properly. I am looking into a work-around.

Comment: I think so, the advice is wrapped in a AdvisedRequestHandler and when interceptor verifies if invocationThis instanceof MessageHandler, it fails.

Comment: I added a not-so-pretty workaround to my answer. You might want to put the interceptor after the JSON has been transformed. I added an [issue to the DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/135).

Comment: BTW, it's already fixed in the 1.2.0.RELEASE version of the DSL if you can upgrade.